# EE2 Structure and structure list closes prematurely

Tags: ee2, structure, admin

We are cleaning up an old client site, and I see that structure closes the  tag halfway down our list of articles. The end result is that half of the page looks like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/auu99oc6z1dn54z/8c2bknqf.png

When I inspect the code, I see that Structure, after a certain amount of entries, just closes the ul tag.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/auu99oc6z1dn54z/nvto40_h.png

Has anyone encountered this previously?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Following the debug commands helped. In the end, I think I performed a clean up that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something isn't right in your structure database. Deleting members and choosing the "delete all entries" option seems to leave the structure database in an inconsistent state. The structure folks include a tool for fixing this sort of thing.

First back up your database.

Then edit 
your_ee_root/expressionengine/third_party/structure/mcp.structure.php
And change

```
var $debug = FALSE;
```

to

```
var $debug = TRUE;
```

This will add a debug button in structure which can fix this issue. click debug and follow the instructions.

Don't forget to turn debug off when your done.

I found the solution in structure's support channel.

https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2339-structure-admin-page-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, we would recommend upgrading to Structure 4.  Structure 4 has the ability to fix this, where in Structure 3.x it would just drop the problem causing pages out of Structure. (Please note, upgrading to Structure 4 when this problem is present will give you the ability to fix the existing broken pages from an older installed version of Structure)

There also hasn't been a known case of this happening in Structure 4.